# How do I write code to select/unselect all checkbox on selecting checkbox header of data grid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I am facing little issues on working with data grid in WPF. Previously I was comfortable with Windows forms.

I have added a checkbox column in data grid and added a checkbox in the header.

Now How do I write code to select/unselect all checkbox on selecting checkbox header?

I tried all the possible answers from other posts but I am unable to success on it. I am little confused somewhere.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="204" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,162,0,48" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="729" AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"  EnableColumnVirtualization="False" IsManipulationEnabled="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn" RowHeight="26" ColumnHeaderHeight="26" FontSize="15">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn >
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Name="SelectAll" ></CheckBox>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What should I do next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# code for select all checkbox in wpf datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756033/c-sharp-code-for-select-all-checkbox-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, you're supposed to use data binding. So in your case, you should data bind a `bool` property to the `CheckBox` in your `Header` and another for each item in the collection:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox Name="SelectAll" IsChecked="{Binding AreAllCheckBoxesChecked, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourWindow}}}" />
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

In this example, the items in your collection will need to have an `IsSelected` property to data bind to the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and your view model or code behind will need an `AreAllCheckBoxesChecked` property to data bind to the `Header Checkbox.IsChecked` property. Then, it's a simple matter of updating the `IsSelected` property of each collection item in the setter of the `AreAllCheckBoxesChecked` property:

```
public bool AreAllCheckBoxesChecked
{
    get { return areAllCheckBoxesChecked; }
    set 
    {
        areAllCheckBoxesChecked = value;
        foreach (YourDataType item in YourCollection)
        {
            item.IsSelected = value;
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("AreAllCheckBoxesChecked"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I give for 'YourDataType' and 'YourCollection'?

    public bool AreAllCheckBoxesChecked
        {
            get { return AreAllCheckBoxesChecked; }
            set
            {
                AreAllCheckBoxesChecked = value;
                foreach (DataGridRow item in dataGrid1.Items)
                {
                    item.IsSelected = value;
                }
                
            }
        }



This is not working.

What should I correct?

Comment: I thought that would be self explanatory... `YourDataType` is the type of class that each of your items is and `YourCollection` is the name of the collection property that you are data binding to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. As for what you should correct... just look at my code again and compare it to yours... there should be a private `bool areAllCheckBoxesChecked` variable as well.

Comment: I am not binding any ItemsSource for data grid. I am binding it in code.
dataGrid1.ItemsSource=dataTable.AsDataView();

Comment: *I am binding it in code*... no you're not... that's not a `Binding`. You need to properly data bind the `ItemsSource` property to a collection property for this to work (which you should be doing anyway). You can still [setup a `Binding` in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind checkboxes to some properties of VM if you are following MVVM, if not, instead of IsSelected, you can have an event handler for checked and unchecked events.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectAll}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can you please show me some code for event handlers for checked and unchecked events?

This is the place I am struck.

Comment: Trust me don't go that route, try and implement using MVVM read about it.